# Is there a way keyboard stroke that can go to the parent folder of the root folder in the finder?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Based on the screenshot below, my root is in my `/Work` directory, and I would like to go to it's parent which is my `/Desktop`. Is there a keystroke or shortcut that can get me there?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>